# Distinct rows while copying data from Excell to MS SQL

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008

I would like to copy data from excel to ms sql database. I have created a table just with column Id (auto increment) and Value (nvarchar). I want to copy data from excel which is a column of 'values'. In this column each value repeats at least once. While copying I would like not to insert value which was inserted earlier. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options -

Option 1 - In excel, select the column with duplicate values and go to - Data->Remove duplicates. This will remove duplicates and then you can insert these values.

Option 2 - In SQL, create unique constraint on Value(nvarchar) column. Now, it will give error for each duplicate value and will not allow insert of duplicate value. Now, Insert your data and then drop that constraint, once insert is complete.